# Locating Server-Grade PSU-to-PCIe Power Cables for Bitmain Antminers?

Tags: mining-setup, antminer, psu

Does anyone know where breaker boards and cables can be purchased online that provides four PCIe 6-pin connectors to power an Antminer C1 from a server-grade power supply unit (PSU)?

Background: I was watching a Spondoolie SP20 Jackson [video](http://www.spondoolies-tech.com/products/holiday-special-sp20-jackson-shipping-from-stock) that showed a server grade power supply and a breaker board that could feed four PCIe connectors. The video got me thinking... I have a couple of high quality 1100 Watt PFE1100-12-054RA 1U server-grade power supplies from canabalizing a dead 1.6 TH/s Cointerra box (was always very unreliable) that would be ashamed to waste.

One PSU's load should be ~94% efficient when powering an Antminer [C1](https://www.bitmaintech.com/productDetail.htm?pid=00020141016120002527iTkNypAG06C9). The problem is the so called "breaker boards" in the dead Cointerra box have 4 AWG copper wires that are used to feed Cointerra mining boards. It would be a very messy hack (requires crimping and potentially a fire hazard) to fashion my own cables to connect the Cointerra "breaker board" to 4 PCIe connectors to power an Antminer C1.

[image: Canabalized Cointerra Breaker Board]

FYSA - The [C1 instructions](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=846095.0) showed a fat paperclip trick to have two ATX power supplies to fully power a C1 that provides the short answer [How to power the Bitmain Antminer C1?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/32672/how-to-power-the-bitmain-antminer-c1) Don't power your Antminer's using Coolmax products... Two Model:ZX-600 died within 30 days while using a C1's Antminer factory default settings. The C1 even burned up an old Butterfly LAbs (BFL) ATX PSU. This was the impetus for this question. From other Internet postings, it appears that server grade PSU should to be used for Bitmain Antminer products. Also if you ordered a C1 without a SysCooling Kit, use [SysCooling Kit](http://shop.syscooling.com/goods.php?id=45) to purchase one after the fact.

Comment: Are you getting the SP20 because I'm having the same problem. I want to get a server grade power supply, however don't know where to get the breaker board and the cables if you already did could you tell me where.

Answer (score 2):

A solution, but still not optimal for me, is on a Bitcoin Forum [posting](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=622783.0).

The server grade HP DPS-800GBA connectors are completely incompatible with [FCI PWRLOPRO](http://download.siliconexpert.com/pdfs/2013/10/31/1/1/47/89/fci_/manual/10108888.pdf) connector that my existing server-grade [PFE1100-12-054RA PSUs](http://www.alliedelec.com/bel-power-solutions-pfe1100-12-054ra/70006075/) connect to.

Wound up canabalizing the Coolmax ATX cables.  Only needed to solder the ends of the cables to prep them for crimping into a 4 AWG lug.  Tested the fashioned cables to make sure the voltage being delivered was indeed 12 volts DC. For now, the PCIe voltage sensing pins are floating, no PSU feedback being supplied. The server PSU is much noisier, but takes up significantly less space, and is about 15% more power efficient than the older ATX PSUs. Will see if everything still works in another month. See the picture below.

[image: Cointerra 1100 Watt PFE1100-12-054RA PSU Powering an Antminer C1]